# Update a Postgres table columns values from another table if same values otherwise insert a new row for unmatched value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like this.Table-b:

| id | deviceSerial | time_difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 636363636890 | 2156 |
| 2 | 636363636891 | 27 |
| 3 | 636363636893 | 178 |
| 4 | 6625839827 | 53 |
| 5 | 6625839828 | 28 |

I have some queries from another table,table-b by this query

```
SELECT 
    deviceSerial, 
    DATE_PART('day', MAX(createdat)::timestamp - MIN(createdat)::timestamp)  * 24 + 
         DATE_PART('hour', MAX(createdat)::timestamp - MIN(createdat)::timestamp) * 60 +
         DATE_PART('minute', MAX(createdat)::timestamp - MIN(createdat)::timestamp) AS time_difference  
FROM 
    table-a 
GROUP BY 
    deviceserial;
```

Queries:

```
| deviceSerial | time_difference |
|--------------|-----------------|
| 636363636890 | 123             |
| 636363636891 | 3               |
| 636363636893 | 178             |
| 6625839827   | 29              |
| 6625839828   | 4               |
| 6625839829   | 10              |
```

Now I Want to insert the values(queries) from table-a,if deviceserial column match,else deviceserial doesn't match insert another records for unmatched reocrds.I want the sum of time_difference values.I want something like this.

```
| id | deviceSerial | time_difference |
|----|--------------|-----------------|
| 1  | 636363636890 | 2279            |
| 2  | 636363636891 | 30             |
| 3  | 636363636893 | 356            |
| 4  | 6625839827   | 82              |
| 5  | 6625839828   | 32              |
| 6  | 6625839829   | 10              |
```

I tried Postgres this query :

```
INSERT INTO table-a (deviceSerial,time_difference) 
    SELECT
        deviceserial,
        SUM(DATE_PART('day', MAX(createdat)::timestamp - 
MIN(createdat)::timestamp) * 24 +
                DATE_PART('hour', MAX(createdat)::timestamp - 
MIN(createdat)::timestamp) * 60 + 
                DATE_PART('minute', MAX(createdat)::timestamp - MIN(createdat)::timestamp)) AS time_difference  
    FROM 
        table-b 
    GROUP BY 
        deviceserial;
```

But I get an error. Can you please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I find your question a bit hard to follow.  But if I understand correctly, you want an UPSERT command -- insert a new device if it is not present otherwise increment the `timedifference` column.  The basic idea is to start with a unique constraint on `deviceSerial` (if you don't have one already):

```
alter table b add constraint unq_b_deviceSerial unique (deviceSerial);
```

Then use `on conflict` for the `insert`:

```
insert into b (deviceSerial, timedifference)
     select deviceSerial, timedifference
        from (<your query here>)
        on conflict (unq_b_deviceSerial) update
            set timedifference = b.timedifference + excluded.dimedifference
```

Comment: Thank you@Gordon Linoff .Sorry for my english.But you understood it correctly .I got some syntax error ,when adding constraint . `events_data=# ALTER TABLE device_usage ADD CONSTRANT unq_b_deviceSerial UNIQUE (deviceSerial);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ...ice_usage ADD CONSTRANT unq_b_deviceSerial UNIQUE (deviceSerial) `

Comment: @saminaw . . . That syntax works in Postgres:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4a82386ed6bce48220ebf3d426aac313.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question a bit confusing, but I guess you could use MERGE

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/55920/sql-merge.html